# How to print a list of value in Excel, after querying a database?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

i've a list of personal function made in Excel VBA. 
This function query a mysql database and return only one value. 
For example, a function GetRevenue return a single value. 
But i'm wondering how to write an excel function that return a List of Value or an entire table ?

Suppose in cell A1 i write my function "GetCustomerList" .. i would like my table returned starting from cell A2.

How to do in VBA, using ADODB ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're calling your function from a worksheet formula, then it can only return values to cells which actually contain that function. It cannot write directrly to other areas of the sheet, or change the sheet in any other way (eg. you cannot use a UDF to update cell fill color, etc)

Comment: You would need to create a UDF which returns an array of values, and enter the worksheet function into a range of cells using Ctrl+Shift+Enter (ie. as an array formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADODB you can simply copy the table from a defined cell using copyfromrecordset method.
The following listing makes the point clear:

```
i = 1

        For Each fld In rd.Fields
           Cells(4, i).Value = fld.Name
            i = i + 1
        Next
        Cells(5, 1).CopyFromRecordset rd
rd.Close
con.Close
```

Here the variable rd refers to Recordset and con the connection object. The entire table is copied from cell (5,1) ie A5. The headers are copied to cells from A4.
I hope you can use the method.